# Ionic changes generating page?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am creating a new page in my new project in ionic.
My steps:

ionic start navigationApp blank --v2 --ts
cd navigationApp
ionic generate page place

and this generate a folder place with place.html, place.ts, place.scss and place.module.ts
Why place.module.ts? before this file doesn't exists. And in this file, I have problem in IonicModule.forChild(Place).

And, before when I use this command I generated PlacePage and now is Place (only place) why?

Thanks!

Comment: can you show your `package.json` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its about the change in new "Ionic 3", with Angular 4 and responsive grids, etc.
There are some changes in Ionic 3 (page.module.ts is one of the changes), for more details see this doc,
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-3-0-0-beta/84540